# How to copy a sqlite table from a disk database to a memory database in python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, copy

How to copy a disk based sqlite table to a memory database in python? I know the schema of the table.

Comment: As this post remains highly visible in search engines and the (current) answer isn't here or in the duplicate link, I'm adding the relevant SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395888/pure-python-backup-of-sqlite3-in-memory-database-to-disk . Short answer: backup API is available in Python 3.7+ : https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.backup

Answer (score 39, accepted):

this code is more general but maybe it can help you:

```
import sqlite3

new_db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # create a memory database

old_db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

query = "".join(line for line in old_db.iterdump())

# Dump old database in the new one. 
new_db.executescript(query)
```

**EDIT :** for getting your specify table you can just change in the for loop like this:

```
name_table = "test_table"  # name of the table that you want to get.

for line in old_db.iterdump():
    if name_table in line:
        query = line
        break
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but how efficient is it?

Comment: @Clay: like i wrote in my answer this code is more general and generic, you can use it for dumping all the database or to dump only a given table, and  for how efficient it is? the code use iterator for once (less memory) and it also create all the database in a single query, which mean no up and go(less communication).

Comment: Thanks! This will help me very much. I do like the flexability of it.

Comment: Is that quadratic? I thought it was better to do query = ''.join([line for line in old_db.iterdump()])

Comment: @wisty : it's not quadratic it's linear (loop one time), but i agree with you that using `str.join` will be more compact and faster, editing my answer ... thanks

Comment: @mouad, in C this may be quadratic, as you are building a string of length N every step. (Actually, average length is N/2, but that's still O(N)). Python may optimize this away though.

Comment: Python implementations now typically see that there is only one reference to a string, so they mutate it for append operations.

Comment: I know this is old I got stuck and wanted to alert the next person: If your app crashes while a memory db is active, you'll get a dump to a file called ':memory'. Next time you run your app, new_db.executescript(query) will raise an exception about tables already existing and such. So you'll want to use something like `dumpfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),':memory')` then check with `os.path.isfile(dumpfile)`. If that returns True, then `os.remove(dumpfile)` will solve the problem. [edited - hit enter too soon]

Comment: If you use quote chars or SQL keywords in your column names you may need to patch your dump.py file. Here is what I ended up using: https://github.com/drbailey/GroupShare/blob/master/sqlite3%20patch/dump.py
This implements the changes here: http://bugs.python.org/file24429/sqlite3dump.patch

Comment: Fine for smaller databases but @wisty has a point about continually building strings.  Write to a TemporaryFile during the dump iteration and then read into executescript() in order to circumvent this?

Comment: `iterdump()` already returns an iterator. You could white `query = "".join(old_db.iterdump())` instead of `query = "".join(line for line in old_db.iterdump())`

Comment: Will  `query = "".join(iterator)` convert the lazy `iterator` into an in-memory string object `query` ? This needs two times the memory: first for the string object, second for the SQLite in-memory db itself.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [SQLite Backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). The example is in C, but this should show you how it's done efficiently.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any C. I did think I heard somewhere that apsw (Another Python Sqlite Wrapper) Had a backup function though. Is this true?

Comment: useful :) i just need something like this! Great thx

Comment: `sqlite3_backup*` C functions are not available via Python sqlite3 API. Though it should be easy to create a C extension for Python that calls them

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, for those using python and sqlalchemy:

http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/apr/27/copying-databases-across-platforms-sqlalchemy/

The idea behind is to replicate the metadata from the source database to the target database and then transfer column after column.