# copy or load sqlite db in memory? C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Theres a few dozen sqlite files i need to process and they are taking a few minutes each. Is there a way to copy or load the db into memory? IO (specifically reads as no writes are being code) is the bottleneck taking up 70% of the time.

Is there a short/quick solution i can use?
Note: It will finish in <40minutes so if it isnt a quick solution it may not be worth the bother.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a "way out there" idea, and with 40 min overhead may not be worth a shot.

[This doc](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) may be of help.Basically, you copy an on-disk DB to a memory one, similar to a [Python example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019081/copy-a-sqlite-table-from-a-disk-database-to-a-memory-database-in-python), then dump it back to disk. Instead of many small writes, you'll be doing a couple large ones.

Again, some testing will be needed to check your specific situation and whether it will help.

Comment: this looks cool, but i dont know the syntax to copy it all from file to memory. I dont know how to do a insert into ThatDBOrFile from thisDBOrFile.

Comment: have you looked at the Python example I suggested. Here's a [Java example](http://code.ca-net.org/SQLite#In-memory_databases). Actually, my method is not that outlandish, just looks weird.

Comment: +1. I dont have any of the functions i see in the python example such as iterdump and executescript. The java looks more similar but not the same. Its close enough.